# Preserve ownership of entire folder hierarchy in tar?

Tags: permissions, tar, ownership

I can preserve ownership of `folderB` and all files and folders inside when creating and extracting a tar file as follows:

```
tar -cpf out.tar folderA/folderB
sudo tar -xpf out.tar --same-owner
```

However, `folderA` is owned by root when extracting unless the folder already exists. Is there any way to preserve ownership of the entire folder hierarchy with tar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because

```
tar -cpf out.tar folderA/folderB
```

doesn’t store `folderA` as a separate object in the tarball, so it doesn’t have any way of recording the ownership and permissions of `folderA`.

To preserve the ownership, you need to tell `tar` to do so when you create the tarball; with GNU `tar` at least, the following works:

```
tar -cpf out.tar --no-recursion folderA --recursion folderA/folderB
```

This stores `folderA` (and its permissions etc.) without recursing, and `folderA/folderB` with its contents.